# When should autosubscribe be called client side in a Meteor app?

Tags: meteor

What is the best practice for calling autosubscribe client side in a Meteor app?

Should it always be in Meteor.startup?

If so, why?

If not, why?

If sometimes, why?

In summary, what is the best practice and what are the trade offs based on the options of putting autosubscribe in the meteor.startup versus not?  I think this is very important at this time for application developers because it significantly affects our application design decisions.

Comment: I'm not yet knowledgeable enough with Meteor to post an answer that addresses all of your questions authoritatively, but my experiences so far tell me to always wrap autosubscribes in Meteor.startup. If I don't, I get occasional empty data on load (empty data being a symptom specific to my app, your results may vary). I have to say it's a rare occurrence, but wrapping in a Meteor.startup alleviates the problem completely.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Autosubscribe has been deprecated and I suspect you want to use autorun now,. It's documented at http://docs.meteor.com/#meteor_autorun

Answer (score 0):

When you want to automatically update the subscription whenever the session variable changes.

**Source:** From the comment in the example at [Meteor.autosubscribe](http://docs.meteor.com/#meteor_autosubscribe).

Comment: I believe the OP is asking *where* to place the autosubscribe call (he should edit the question).

Answer (score 0):

From tests I have done it does seem that putting your autosubscribe in Meteor.startup is the safest solution if you need those collections to have some kind of data population or start populating before view rendering.  I experienced similar issues that @matb33 has reported with empty data on load and placing autosubscribe in Meteor.startup on the client solved the problem.

Note that [`autosubscribe` is now gone](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/meteor-core/mTa81RLvhbY), and replaced with `autorun`.